# Use Facebook authentication token in API

Tags: ios, facebook, api, access-token

I'm having an iOS app where the user authenticates with Facebook on the device and also communicating with my server API.

**Authentication**

Today I'm sending the Facebook user access token (over SSL) and the server verifies the token with Facebook. Thats the authentication mechanism for the API.

**Session token**

Instead of using a generated token to user for all future API calls, I use the Facebook access token as the session token as well. This makes it a lot easier on the device as you don't have to care about first getting the token and then call the API. You just send the Facebook token in each call, easy.

**Is this a good solution when authenticating with Facebook towards an API?**

Comment: It is a decent solution, but whenever you launch the app from scratch or creates a session, then the app access token refreshes, so make sure you also update your DB with your latest token. For Eg: Access tokens are valid for 60 days, but if a user visits the app on day 1 and gave all the permissions, and app sends the token to server on day1, user revisits on day 7, app launches from scratch then in this case the token will be refreshed,and the token will be valid for 60 days since the day it was refreshed.On server you don't need to extend the token anymore,you just need to update the db.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is the token refreshed both when the client and the server calls the Facebook API? So in practice I can use the server to keep the token alive longer?

Comment: Na Na No, Token can only be refreshed on the client side. You need to play around with - Session class method openWithCompletionHandler, this will do the crazy refreshing of token for you.. Server can only pull the data from FB on the basis of token, but can't refresh it for you, until and unless you opt for Short live tokens on client and pass it on to server for making it extended one, which ain't a good idea I believe. There are many tutorials etc available on SSO (Single Sign Ons), so that user dont have to go through the login process again and again..