# Authentication and login to my app with Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, authentication, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using the `Facebook iOS SDK` to allow quick sign-up of users in my app. Here is the flow:

- User taps "Login with Facebook" button
- Taken to Facebook app or Safari for login
- Redirected back to my app
- Show Sign-up for with pre-filled fields from `FBGraphUser` object
- User creates account using data from Facebook

After they created an account, is it possible to authenticate with Facebook, and let them login to my app without having to enter the username and password they just created? How would the flow of that work?

Seems like I should be able to do the following:

- User taps on "Login with Facebook" button
- Authenticate with Facebook SDK
- Return to app, and make a call to server, checking to see if there is a username matching the Facebook email
- Allow the user into the app with no password, since they have authenticated with Facebook and have an account in our system.

Is this the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

That is very close. However, it is not enough to just check that the email/username is valid. It is strongly recommended to validate the token directly with Facebook as well.

See [Use Facebook authentication token in API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18336400/567493) for a very similar concept and the Facebook docs about verifying token: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests.